# Knockout JS textInput after event

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am having trouble using the textInput binding with a custom autocomplete/dropdown function.  I am using the textInput binding so I do see the view model get updated, but the update takes place after the keypress event which is what my autocomplete is bound too.  Here is my autocomplete function:

```js
$("#table-body").on("keypress", ".combo", function (e) {
    var item = ko.dataFor(e.target),
        drop = $(".dropdown-menu", this);

    if (item.Name() !== undefined && item.Name().length === 0) {
        $(".input-group-btn", this).removeClass("open");
    } else if (item.Name() !== undefined && item.Name() !== null && item.Name() !== "") {
        drop.children().not(":containsNoCase(" + item.Name() + ")").hide();
        drop.children().filter(":containsNoCase(" + item.Name() + ")").show();
        $(".input-group-btn", this).addClass("open");
    }
});
```

In the event above, item.Name() is null or whitespace when the first character is entered, and then is always 1 character behind what is typed.  Any ideas on how I can change the event capture to be after the textInput has updated the view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that the update of the model value takes so long and gets set so late in the game. I looked at the textInput binding source and found that knockout defers the setting of the value by 4ms when the input is changed. Might explain why the value is not updated at the time the handler is run?

```
var deferUpdateModel = function (event) {
        if (!timeoutHandle) {
            // The elementValueBeforeEvent variable is set *only* during the brief gap between an
            // event firing and the updateModel function running. This allows us to ignore model
            // updates that are from the previous state of the element, usually due to techniques
            // such as rateLimit. Such updates, if not ignored, can cause keystrokes to be lost.
            elementValueBeforeEvent = element.value;
            var handler = DEBUG ? updateModel.bind(element, {type: event.type}) : updateModel;
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(handler, 4);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Ah I missed that going through source.  So I either need to wrap in a timeout to get around the delay from textInput or else use dom selector

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with the `setTimeout`. The `textInput` binding usually will watch the `input` event, and this event is fired after `keypress`: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#keypress-event-order

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually binding to the keypress event, I would consider using a knockout subscription on your Name observable. By doing do, you can be assured that you have the latest value and won't have to worry about the 1-behind problem. Whipped up a quick fiddle to demonstrate.

```
vm.name.subscribe(function(val){
    var name = val,
    drop = $(".dropdown-menu");

    if (name !== undefined && name.length === 0) {
         $(".input-group-btn").removeClass("open");
    } else if (name !== undefined && name !== null && name !== "") {
         drop.children().not(":contains(" + name + ")").hide();
         drop.children().filter(":contains(" + name + ")").show();
         $(".input-group-btn").addClass("open");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttz0p33n/

Comment: Problem with this is I lose the DOM context which I need for updating the auto complete.  I was trying to avoid needing to write a custom binding for this because there are other events that I need to hook into

Comment: Hm, that is tricky. Is the element the keypress event is bound to an input element? Could you evaluate $(this).val() in the binding to get the current textual value of the input?

Comment: Or could you find the input element value with the scope. $("input", this).val()

Comment: Yeah that is an option, I was hoping to just use the knockout view models and avoid a query selector for the data.  If no one has another suggestion I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: One more option.. could wrap it in a small timeout. http://jsfiddle.net/ttz0p33n/5/